# Updating local Sql Server Database from Cloud Snowflake Server fastest way to get new data

Tags: sql-server, insert, local

I have a local SQL Server DB table with about 5 million records.
I snowflake server that has a similar table that is updated daily. 
I need to update my local table with the new records that are added on the Snowflake table.

This code works but it takes about an hour to retrieve about 200,000 records. I insert the records into a local temp table and then insert them into my Sql server db.

Is there a faster way to retrieve the records from Snowflake and get them into SQL Server?

TIA
JohnB

SELECT      A.*
into        #Sale2020New
FROM        OPENQUERY(SNOW, 'SELECT * FROM "DATA"."PUBLIC"."Sales"  where "Sales"."Date" >= ''1/1/2020'' and "Sales"."Date" <= ''12/31/2020'' ') A
Left JOIN   [SnowFlake].[dbo].Sale2020 B
ON          B.PrimaryKey = A.PrimaryKey
WHERE
            b.PrimaryKey IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Does it take 1 hour just retrieving data from Snowflake or the whole process?

To speed up data retrieval from Snowflake, implement clustering on DATE column in snowflake table. This would prune micropartitions and avoid full table scan. You can get more information on clustering [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html)

As for delta load, instead of a join you can apply filter on DATE column to current date and this will avoid a costly join operation and filter data at the start.

```
     SELECT * FROM "SALES" 
 where "Sales"."Date" = '2020-04-07'
```